# Toolbar se solapa con la status bar con Android usando windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode shortEdges

Tags: android

implementando mostrar una actividad a pantalla completa y que use todo el lienzo posible, hasta el espacio del notch para un visor de imágenes, me encuentro que la toolbar queda medio solapado por la statusbar al poner la vista en horizontal, en vertical se visualiza bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Theme.xml

```xml
<style name="Base.Theme.PhotoViewer" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">shortEdges</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentación oficial de [Display content edge-to-edge in your ap](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge)

Primero hago que la toolbar se printe por debajo de la statusbar, porque si lo hago despues solamente funciona correcctamente en vertical

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_oval_filled"
            app:popupTheme="?attr/actionBarPopupTheme"
            app:title=" ">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Para detectar que espacio ocupa los elementos de usuario del sistema se usará `windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility`

```kotlin
private fun initWindowsInsets() {
    //Setting top margin toolbar
    binding.toolbar.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, windowInsets ->
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            (view.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams).topMargin = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()).top
        }
        windowInsets
    }
}
```